# PHP login script not "refreshing" in some browsers

Tags: php, authentication

I am experiencing very difficult (hard to find) problem with my PHP login script. I am using sessions to make login work with standard send form and using this script:

```
public function login($user, $password)
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($password))
    {    
      $user = $web->esc($user);
      $password = $web->Hash($user, $password);

      $db->selectDb('login');
      $qw = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='".$user."' AND pass='".$password."'");

      if (mysql_num_rows($qw) > 0)      
      {    
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($qw);
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result['username'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['id'];  
        return true; 
...
...
```

And in login I am using something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{
  if($auth->login($_POST["name"], $_POST["pass"]))
  {
    header("location: ./");  
  }
}
else         
...
...
```

It is working quite ok but in Opera and sometimes other browsers there is a problem. When I log in in Opera, Google Chrome etc for example - fill in my form and send it - it just "stucks" on login form and never let me see my page after login - it is working in other browsers - I just do not see the problem why in some browsers it is not wokring. DO you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Not completely related with the question but I hope you escaped `$user` and `$password` inputs (to prevent SQL injection).

Comment: Like how escaped? ... Problem is that ater login there is still "login form" instead new page in "header("location: ./");" which is different after login.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `$web->esc` part. Anyway, have you tried putting a `return;` after `header('location:./');`. I had some troubles with it sometimes, too.

Comment: where is $web initialised? It doesn't appear to be in scope do you mean $this->web

Comment: Seems it is working only sometimes this return code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK problem solved after having these errors:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_5019088d181146779ffc848a095c27ff, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0
```

In settings in php.ini changing this:

```
session.save_path = /tmp
```

Everything works fine thx to Mihai Stancu for error analysis code.

Answer (score 1):

After an header location: you have to be sure that PHP will no send data.
So try to put the function `exit();` just after the header function.

Comment: So exit really works thank you :) Just needed to delete cache after it.

Answer (score 1):

Activate error reporting and display errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('scream.enabled', TRUE);
```

It should show you a "Warning headers already sent in file **file** on line **line**".

It would be preferable if you wrote the error reporting statements somewhere inside the first index.php file and the code was included by your index. Because parse errors in the current file aren't shown it just gives you a white screen.